# Angular create table from json resulting in sorted headings

Tags: json, angularjs

I have an angular app in which i am creating a table based on the json as follows:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in resultData[0]">
      {{header}}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in resultData">
    <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
      {{cell}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here the table creates the headings as well as the content from a `json`. But the result of this code is a table with **sorted headings**. Is there a way to keep the order the same as in the `json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Your headers are in an object. JavaScript objects do not guarantee property order. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). To preserve order, you have to use an array in your JSON file.